# How to add noise mode in Sampler (SamplerQNN) in qiskit for quantum neural network?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming, quantum-algorithms, quantum-neural-network

I would like to add a noise model to one of the tutorial examples of quantum machine learning in the Qiskit site (PyTorch QGAN implementation).

I used the following codes

```
sampler_n = AerSampler()
sampler_n.set_options(noise_model=noise_model)
```

instead of

```
sampler = Sampler(options={ "shots": shots, "seed": algorithm_globals.random_seed})
```

Whenever the quantum circuit is well-defined (does not have any parameters), such as

```
weights_n = algorithm_globals.random.random(qc_zofal.num_parameters)
def create_generator() -> TorchConnector:
    p = qc_zofal.assign_parameters(weights_n)
    qnn = SamplerQNN(
        sampler = sampler_n,
        circuit= p,
        input_params=[],
        weight_params=p.parameters,
        sparse=False,
    )    
    return TorchConnector(qnn, [])

generator_n = create_generator()
print(generator_n)
print(generator_n(torch.tensor([])).reshape(-1,1))   
print(generator.parameters)
```

Everything is ok. But if I put a parametric circuit in it, I encounter the following error:

```
WARNING:qiskit_aer.backends.aerbackend:Simulation failed and returned the following error message:
ERROR: Failed to load circuits: Invalid parameterized qobj: instruction param position out of range
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/result/result.py in _get_experiment(self, key)
    367             try:
--> 368                 exp = self.results[key]
    369             except IndexError as ex:

IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

QiskitError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
14 frames
QiskitError: 'Result for experiment "0" could not be found.'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

QiskitMachineLearningError                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit_machine_learning/neural_networks/sampler_qnn.py in _forward(self, input_data, weights)
    360             results = job.result()
    361         except Exception as exc:
--> 362             raise QiskitMachineLearningError("Sampler job failed.") from exc
    363         result = self._postprocess(num_samples, results)
    364 

QiskitMachineLearningError: 'Sampler job failed.'
```

Could you please help me How can I fix this error?

And my next question is: How can I access the QNN parameters after each training from pytorchconnector?

Answer (score 1):

To add noise in Aer it's done via the `backend_options` supplied to the primitive. Here is an [example using the Aer Estimator primitive](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/algorithms/03_vqe_simulation_with_noise.html#Performance-with-noise) but the technique is the same for Aer Sampler.

For the QGAN maybe check out the [Qiskit Machine Learning PyTorch qGAN tutorial](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/machine-learning/tutorials/04_torch_qgan.html) where you can see there it shows the parameterized circuit it is using.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the Qiskit tutorial did not consider the noise model. backend_options for the parametric quantum circuit with Aer sampler lead to the above error.                                                                                                      
sampler_n = AerSampler()

sampler_n.set_options(noise_model=noise_model)